# Why would using a temp table vs a table variable improve the speed of this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I currently have a performance issue with a query (that is more complicated than the example below).  Originally the query would run and take say 30 seconds, then when I switched out the use of a table variable to using a temp table instead, the speed is cut down to a few seconds.

Here is a trimmed down version using a table variable:

```
-- Store XML into tables for use in query
DECLARE @tCodes TABLE([Code] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO
    @tCodes
SELECT 
    ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Code'
FROM 
    @xmlCodes.nodes('/ArrayOfString/string') AS ParamValues(ID)


SELECT
    'SummedValue' = SUM(ot.[Value])
FROM
    [SomeTable] st (NOLOCK)
JOIN
    [OtherTable] ot (NOLOCK)
    ON  ot.[SomeTableID] = st.[ID]
WHERE
    ot.[CodeID] IN (SELECT [Code] FROM @tCodes) AND 
    st.[Status] = 'ACTIVE' AND
    YEAR(ot.[SomeDate]) = 2013 AND  
    LEFT(st.[Identifier], 11) = @sIdentifier
```

Here is the version with the temp table which performs MUCH faster:

```
SELECT 
    ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Code'
INTO
    #tCodes
FROM 
    @xmlCodes.nodes('/ArrayOfString/string') AS ParamValues(ID)


SELECT
    'SummedValue' = SUM(ot.[Value])
FROM
    [SomeTable] st (NOLOCK)
JOIN
    [OtherTable] ot (NOLOCK)
    ON  ot.[SomeTableID] = st.[ID]
WHERE
    ot.[CodeID] IN (SELECT [Code] FROM #tCodes) AND 
    st.[Status] = 'ACTIVE' AND
    YEAR(ot.[SomeDate]) = 2013 AND  
    LEFT(st.[Identifier], 11) = @sIdentifier
```

The problem I have with performance is solved with the change but I just don't understand why it fixes the issue and would prefer to know why.  It could be related to something else in the query but all I have changed in the stored proc (which is much more complicated) is to switch from using a table variable to using a temp table.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at this Article very informative http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/yet-another-temp-tables-vs-table-variables-article

Comment: @Steve Wellens Google... who would have thought to use that before coming here and posting a question???

Comment: @M.Ali thanks for the link, and it is similar to other stuff I have read but my results seem to be the opposite of what I would have suspected.

Comment: Two main reasons in my opinion: a **real** temp table (`#temp`) will allow you to define **statistics** (so SQL Server's query optimizer will know how many rows it's dealing with - the `@temp` table var is always treated as containing just a single row, which can badly skey the execution plan causing poor performance), and secondly: you can define indexes on a `#temp` table if it's longer living to further speed up things

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the comment.  The XML 'codes' that are being passed in all cases are static (codes coming from a separate app/db) and contain around 130 items.  The only thing I can make sense of so far is that maybe the recompile from the temp table approach could be affecting it...  it's consistently slow using the table var vs the temp table.  I just hate fixing something and not understand the why behind the fix.

Comment: With `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` it will take account of the number of rows in the table variable which is probably the main reason for different plans in this case.

Comment: @Martin Smith BINGO.  I just add that to the temp variable version and it runs as fast at the temp table version.  Both you and marc_s helped a lot.  Please post your answers so I can at least award you with an upvote and a correct answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences and similarities between table variables and `#temp` tables are looked at in depth [in my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/3690).

Regarding the two queries you have shown (unindexed table variable vs unindexed temp table) three possibilities spring to mind.

1. `INSERT ... SELECT` to table variables is always serial. The `SELECT` can be parallelised for temp tables.
2. Temp tables can have column statistics histograms auto created for them.
3. Usually the cardinality of table variables is assumed to be `0` (when they are compiled when the table is empty)

From the code you have shown (3) seems the most likely explanation.

This can be resolved by using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to recompile the statement after the table variable has been populated.